# agm-markers not rendering when IconUrl given

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps-api-3

I a trying to render icons for agm-marks using iconUrl, but nothing is showing, also i would like to the the same for Symbol syntax.

I have looked at all the solution involving icon objects, but it is not working.

```html
<agm-marker-cluster [imagePath]="imagePath" [minimumClusterSize]="15">    
    <agm-marker [iconUrl]="'https://github.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers/blob/master/images/marker_black.png'"
        [opacity]="'1'"
        [visible]="'true'"
        *ngFor="let order of orders_data | keyvalue" 
        [latitude]="order.value.member_address_latitude"  
        [longitude]="order.value.member_address_longitude"
        [markerClickable]="true"
        (markerClick)="orderClicked(order)"
        ></agm-marker>
    </agm-marker-cluster>
```

Comment: the problem is your URL. if you click on the url is taking you to the file inside of a repo on github. You need to download the file and put it in your assests folder inside your app

Comment: Thank you, will try that. One more thing, how to go about rendering Symbols? 
 @PatricioVargas . Can you point me to a working example where Symbols are rendered on Map?